# A characterization for a commutative ring with a special intersection property for prime ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ with the property that for any infinite family $\{P_i\}_{i\in I}$ of distinct prime ideals of $R$ we have $\cap_{i\not= j} P_i\subseteq P_j$ for all but fnitely many  $j\in I$. Is there any characterization for  such a ring?

Comment: I suggest revising the title to include some keywords such as "infinite prime avoidance."

Comment: @Steven Landsburg: Clearly the statement  is true if $P_i's$ are not distinct and since I have stated ** for any infinite family=for every infinite family** it means that we are working on an arbitrary family of distinct prime ideals.

Comment: I have the following obvious/extreme examples and counter-examples in mind and I am wondering if you have discovered richer and subtler illustrations to work with. Examples: (1) Finite rings, valuation rings (more generally uniserial rings) (2) UFDs, Dedekind domains. Counter-examples: rings which surject onto a direct product of infinitely many rings. I am also wondering whether anything can be said about meet-irreducible rings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_ring).